# Programmatically turn OFF or ON Aspects

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I have aspects in my spring web application annotated with `@Aspect`. I want to disable or enable aspects at runtime through some services. Is is possible to completely turn off or on aspects based on some settings? I have aspects for logging but I only want those aspects running when I enable logging.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think it's possible. The closest way I can come up with is to add an `if(foo.Configuration.isLoggingEnabled)` in your Pointcut definition.

Comment: `if()` pointcuts are pretty cheap, so this should solve the problem. The reason why you cannot completely remove an aspect is simple: Its byte code is woven into the core code, which is the basic principle of AspectJ. Maybe there are ways to disable dynamic proxies in Spring AOP, I don't know. If "during runtime" in your case means "during application start-up", you can use LTW (or not) to the same effect and only weave based on a config setting.

Comment: here, runtime means when application is loaded. I need to disable Aspects through ui settings.